# Change in instance variable not getting updated in tuple referring the same variable

Tags: python, class, tuples, instance-variables

For this code when I change `x` to `k` using `change()` and then call `self.co` it does not return the updated value of `self.x`. How do I fix this kind of problem generally (this is a basic example)?

```
class scope:
    tag=1
    def __init__(self,h,x):
        self.h = h
        self.x = x
        self.co=(self.x,self.h)
    def change(self,k):
        self.x=k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not change the `self.co attribute`. You are assigning to `self.co` only when initialization of `scope` occurs, that is, when you call `scope()`.Also Python doesn't keep references like pointers in c so changing one would not change the other.

To prove this run this code:

```
class scope:
    tag=1
    def __init__(self,h,x):
        self.h = h
        self.x = x
        self.co=(self.x,self.h)
    def change(self,k):
        self.x=k

s = scope(2,3)
print(s.co)
print("id of self.x before change:", id(s.x)) #11161896
print("id of self.co's x before change:", id(s.co[0])) #11161896
s.change(6)
print(s.co)
print("id of self.x after change:", id(s.x))  #11161824
print("id of self.co's x after change:", id(s.co[0])) #11161896
```

The id are the memory location of the object, and you can see it first starts out the same, but then when you change `self.x` the memory location in the `co` doesn't change

You have to update `self.co` in your `change()`. If you want a dynamically changing co without manually updating it, write a method to retrieve co.

Option 1:

```
class scope:
    tag=1
    def __init__(self,h,x):
        self.h = h
        self.x = x
        self.co=(self.x,self.h)
    def change(self,k):
        self.x=k 
        self.co = (self.x,self.h)
```

Option 2:

```
class scope:
    tag=1
    def __init__(self,h,x):
        self.h = h
        self.x = x
    def change(self,k):
        self.x=k
    def co(self):
        return (self.x,self.h)

s = scope(2,3)
print(s.co()) #(3,2)
s.change(6)
print(s.co()) #(6,2)
```

You can add to method 2 with a decorator `@property` to not make it a function call but at this point, I have no idea what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `self.co` as [*property*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) of class via using `@property` decorator. For example:

```
class Scope:
    tag=1
    def __init__(self,h,x):
        self.h = h
        self.x = x
    def change(self,k):
        self.x=k
    @property
    def co(self):
        return (self.x, self.h)
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> s = Scope(3, 5)
>>> s.co   # initial value
(5, 3)
>>> s.change(45)  # update value of `self.x`
>>> s.co   # updated value
(45, 3)
```

Here, on calling `self.co` will return the dynamic value of `(self.x, self.y)` each time is called.

---

**Issue with your code:** In your code, when you initialized `self.co = (self.x,self.h)` in your `__init__`, a new tuple `self.co` was created holding the value of `(self.x, self.y)` *(which was not holding the reference to these variable)*. Hence, when you updated `self.x`, it was not updated in your tuple object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call function with the name it is defined
Second you can use global keyword also
For example

```
value = 10
Update()
def Update():
    global value
    value = 11
```